# Azure DevOps Pipeline forever stuck in Pending

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We've got an Azure DevOps Pipeline running on a self-hosted against without parallelism that is not running it's Deployment Job or Step.

The version I'm posting below will have two stages, but note that I have tried this by removing the second stage and converting the entire stage to a job, and still the same result. I should also note that I've got multiple pipelines with multiple jobs that run just fine, it seems to be an issue with the specific deployment job.

The second stage is forever stuck in Pending ("Job is Pending"). It will *never* proceed to start running.

[image: First Attempt]

[image: Deploy Stage Not Started]

[image: Job is Pending]

The stage can also not be cancelled, and per the image above, it's been stuck for 2 months.
I should also note that I have submitted this to the Azure Developer Community at developercommunity.visualstudio.com, but I think they've abandoned my ticket.

I'm sure that there are many successful CI/CD deployments in Azure DevOps, I just can't tell what I'm doing wrong here. I am utilizing a working method in our separate Release Pipelines that we are running manually.

Below is the affected pipeline, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
  trigger: none

  variables:
    ArtifactPackageName: 'app.zip'
    DeploySite.IISDeploymentType: 'IISWebsite'
    DeploySite.ActionIISWebsite: 'CreateOrUpdateWebsite'
    DeploySite.WebsiteName: 'REDACTED'
    DeploySite.WebsitePhysicalPath: '%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\REDACTED'
    DeploySite.AddBinding: false
    DeploySite.VirtualPathForApplication: '/REDACTED'
    DeploySite.AppPoolName: 'REDACTED'
    DeploySite.VirtualApplication: 'REDACTED'
    DeploySite.Package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(ArtifactPackageName)
    DeploySite.RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
    DeploySite.TakeAppOfflineFlag: true
    DeploySite.XmlTransformation: false
    DeploySite.XmlVariableSubstitution: true
    DeploySite.SetParametersFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/REDACTED.SetParameters.xml
    DeploySite.JSONSettingsFiles: '**/appsettings.json'

  stages:
  - stage: 'Build'
    displayName: 'Build'
    jobs:
    - job: 'Build'
      displayName: 'Build'
      pool:
        name: REDACTED
      variables:
        Solution: '**/*.sln'
        BuildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
        BuildConfiguration: 'Release'
      steps:
      - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
        displayName: 'Install NuGet Tools'
      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        displayName: 'Restore NuGet Packages'
        inputs:
          restoreSolution: '$(Solution)'
      - task: VSBuild@1
        displayName: 'MSBuild'
        inputs:
          solution: '$(Solution)'
          msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\$(ArtifactPackageName)"'
          platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
          configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: 'Publish Build Artifacts'
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          ArtifactName: drop
          publishLocation: 'Container'
          
  - stage: 'Deploy'
    displayName: 'Deploy'
    dependsOn: 'Build'
    jobs:
    - deployment: 'Deploy'
      displayName: 'Deploy'
      continueOnError: false
      timeoutInMinutes: 10
      workspace:
        clean: all
      pool:
        name: REDACTED
      environment:
        name: SERVER-DEV
        resourceType: VirtualMachine
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - download: current
              displayName: 'Download Artifact'
              artifact: drop
            - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
              displayName: 'Stop IIS App Pool'
              continueOnError: false
              inputs:
                IISDeploymentType: IISApplicationPool
                ActionIISApplicationPool: StopAppPool
                StartStopRecycleAppPoolName: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
            - task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
              displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
              continueOnError: false
              inputs:
                WebSiteName: '$(DeploySite.WebsiteName)'
                VirtualApplication: '$(DeploySite.VirtualApplication)'
                Package: '$(DeploySite.Package)'
                RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: $(DeploySite.RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag)
                SetParametersFile: $(DeploySite.SetParametersFile)
                TakeAppOfflineFlag: $(DeploySite.TakeAppOfflineFlag)
                XmlTransformation: $(DeploySite.XmlTransformation)
                XmlVariableSubstitution: $(DeploySite.XmlVariableSubstitution)
                JSONFiles: $(DeploySite.JSONSettingsFiles)
            - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
              displayName: 'Start IIS App Pool'
              continueOnError: true
              inputs:
                IISDeploymentType: IISApplicationPool
                ActionIISApplicationPool: StartAppPool
                StartStopRecycleAppPoolName: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
```

Comment: If job didn't started ot seems it is waiting for available agent. Are you sure there is at least one free agent in your pool?

Comment: I am sure. We have only one agent, but I can continue to queue tasks on that agent over and over again and they will pick up and run just fine.

Comment: Having exact same problem, but there's no mention of 'deploy' keyword or anything like it

Comment: How do you kill those hanging jobs?

Comment: @Mike Canceling the job eventually causes it to drop off, but I can't recall how long it took

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same error.
I renamed `- deployment: Deploy` to `- deployment: Deployment`
...and it started to work.

Comment: I... I am at a loss for words. I thought that section was for the name. It is working now, just fine.

Thank you so very much for this!

Comment: I found a reference to "deploy" being a [keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#schema) in the docs, and there's also a reference in the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#my-pipeline-is-stuck-with-the-message-job-is-pending-how-can-i-fix-this)

Comment: This is just insane, had the same issue!!!

Answer (score 3):

Changed
from   *- deployment: Deploy* To  *- deployment: Deployment*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error on a stage with only a **Deployment job**.

A successful workaround is to replace the [Deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) with a regular [Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). However, this approach won't keep your deployment history or allow a deployment strategy.

In your case, the `Deploy` would be:

```
- stage: 'Deploy'
  displayName: 'Deploy'
  dependsOn: 'Build'
  jobs:
  - job: 'Deploy'
    displayName: 'Deploy'
    continueOnError: false
    timeoutInMinutes: 10
    workspace:
      clean: all
    pool:
      name: REDACTED
    steps:
    - download: current
      displayName: 'Download Artifact'
      artifact: drop
    - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
      displayName: 'Stop IIS App Pool'
      continueOnError: false
      inputs:
        IISDeploymentType: IISApplicationPool
        ActionIISApplicationPool: StopAppPool
        StartStopRecycleAppPoolName: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
    - task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
      displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
      continueOnError: false
      inputs:
        WebSiteName: '$(DeploySite.WebsiteName)'
        VirtualApplication: '$(DeploySite.VirtualApplication)'
        Package: '$(DeploySite.Package)'
        RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: $(DeploySite.RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag)
        SetParametersFile: $(DeploySite.SetParametersFile)
        TakeAppOfflineFlag: $(DeploySite.TakeAppOfflineFlag)
        XmlTransformation: $(DeploySite.XmlTransformation)
        XmlVariableSubstitution: $(DeploySite.XmlVariableSubstitution)
        JSONFiles: $(DeploySite.JSONSettingsFiles)
    - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
      displayName: 'Start IIS App Pool'
      continueOnError: true
      inputs:
        IISDeploymentType: IISApplicationPool
        ActionIISApplicationPool: StartAppPool
        StartStopRecycleAppPoolName: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
```

Comment: This looks good, but how do you specify the environment (VM or resource) to deploy to? I see the environment property was invalid in the tasks.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to set the Environment either. In my use case that was not an impediment, but I understand that it is an actual drawback.